# Jar from Alice project in Netbeans not working

Tags: java, netbeans, alice

After using Netbeans to create a runnable jar from an existing Alice 3 project, I get the following error:

> system property: org.alice.ide.rootDirectory is not set

and it seems to me that it is set. I am using Linux Mint. Java works. Other runnable jar files work. The plug-ins match. In the Netbeans project properties, the default VM option includes this line:

```
-Dorg.Alice.ide.rootDirectory="${libs.Alice3Library.src}_root"
```

I am at a loss. Please help.

Comment: Please, take some time and read the section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We need a whole lot more info to help you. Pretend Im a 10 year old kid and explain the problem to me

Comment: On Linux Mint 17, I was able to create a simple project in Alice 3. Using the Netbeans Alice plug-in, I created a "new project based on existing Alice project." I then tested that in Netbeans and created a jar from that. When I double click on the jar, I get the error that says the directory is not set. In the Netbeans settings, it seems to be set (using default values) and I have no idea what else should be there instead. I don't know what else I can say.

Comment: The error says it requires property called "org.alice.ide.rootDirectory". Since its added as VM option in netbeans, it is working. Try adding "-Dorg.Alice.ide.rootDirectory="${libs.Alice3Library.src}_root" when you launch the jar file.

Comment: I just tried that suggestion of running it from the terminal and adding that -Dorg... part. I get "bad substitution" error.

Answer (score 1):

The Alice Project should have a fix for this in a future release (we have a bug filed, but a small staff)

---

For current users there is a work around.

At runtime the ApplicationRoot is setup and reads the property "org.alice.ide.rootDirectory".
In there it looks for the platform directory that holds the OS specific libraries like jogl and ffmpeg.

Set this property before ApplicationRoot is used. This can be done in the first line of Progam.main() by calling:

```
  System.setProperty("org.alice.ide.rootDirectory", "./");
```

You will also need to copy the platform folder that holds the required libraries into dist (next to the lib folder). It can be found in the Netbeans build directory in src/aliceSource.jar_root/platform